# How to address specific array element in complex data structure in perl

Tags: perl

I have a complex json data structure in perl like in the following example. I want to address an array element and store data.

Variable

```
$VAR1 = {
  'dummy' => 'foo',
  'profiles' => {
    'Tags' => [
                {
                  '###PLACEHOLDER###',
                }
              ],
}
```

I can for example add an element at "###PLACEHOLDER###" but want later in the perl script to add beneath that Placeholder additional information.
Normally i would address these elements with $var->{profiles}->{Tags}->{PLACEHOLDER} but this is not working with an array.

I dont want to create everytime a foreach loop when i know the name exactly.

Any advice?

Comment: You can address the hash in the array (element 0) like this: `$data{profiles}{Tags}[0]{"###PLACEHOLDER###"} = "data"`

Comment: But this is an array and the values are not sorted so I cant be sure to get the correct one.

Comment: can you save the correct index (into the array) in a variable?

Comment: Yeah i think so, how can I do that?

Comment: So if the index is saved in `$i`, then you do `$data{profiles}{Tags}[$i]{"###PLACEHOLDER###"} = "data"`

Comment: I would advise you to create an object oriented class for such a complex nested data structure, then provide methods which allow you to add data in a manner that suits the semantics of your object.

Comment: Thanks to all i will give that a try

Comment: _"But this is an array and the values are not sorted so I cant be sure to get the correct one."_ Are you sure you want an array in the first place and not another layer of hashes, such as a hash of tags, with the tag names as its keys?

Comment: Your example structure is not valid Perl, so your example code will not work for a hash.  Are you using the hash _key_ or the hash _value_ as the placeholder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[UPDATE: used `dpathr` instead of `dpath` for the references to structures]**

**[UPDATE: used `dpath` instead of `dpathr` for the references to elements]**

[Data::DPath](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::DPath) can do what you require.  Here's code which returns a reference to any structure (hash or array) which contains an element whose value is `###PLACEHOLDER###`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use Data::DPath qw[ dpath dpathr ];

my $struct = {
    'dummy'    => 'foo',
    'profiles' => {
        'ARRAY' => [ '###PLACEHOLDER###' ],
        'HASH' => { key => '###PLACEHOLDER###' },
    },
};

my $path = dpath( '//[value eq "###PLACEHOLDER###"]/..' );

my @matches = $path->match( $struct );

print Dumper \@matches;
```

It results in:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            '###PLACEHOLDER###'
          ],
          {
            'key' => '###PLACEHOLDER###'
          }
        ];
```

If you want direct access to the element, change the path to

```
my $path = dpathr( '//*[value eq "###PLACEHOLDER###"]' );
```

with the result:

```
$VAR1 = [
          \'###PLACEHOLDER###',
          \'###PLACEHOLDER###'
        ];
```

Comment: It does on my machine. What does it do on your machine?

Comment: Right.  Good catch.  Nested references to the structures. I'll fix that.  If the OP wants to directly change the `###PLACEHOLDER###` string they'll still need a reference to the value.  [Now I see what I did.  I switched `dpathr` with `dpath` for the two cases when I was creating the post.  Ooops]

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what you what "adding an element at `###PLACEHOLDER###`" means. Elements can be added *to* arrays and hashes, and it's not clear to which array or hash you are referring.

---

To append an element to the array referenced by `$var->{profiles}{Tags}`, use

```
push @{ $var->{profiles}{Tags} }, $val;
```

This results in

```
$VAR1 = {
  'dummy' => 'foo',
  'profiles' => {
    'Tags' => [
                {
                  '###PLACEHOLDER###' => undef,
                },
                $val
              ],
}
```

---

To add an element to the hash referenced by the last element of the array referenced by `$var->{profiles}{Tags}`, use

```
$var->{profiles}{Tags}[-1]{$key} = $val;
```

This results in

```
$VAR1 = {
  'dummy' => 'foo',
  'profiles' => {
    'Tags' => [
                {
                  '###PLACEHOLDER###' => undef,
                  $key => $val,
                },
              ],
}
```

Of course, if `$key` is `###PLACEHOLDER###`, this results in

```
$VAR1 = {
  'dummy' => 'foo',
  'profiles' => {
    'Tags' => [
                {
                  '###PLACEHOLDER###' => $val,
                },
              ],
}
```